# Render a orthogonal perspective

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, camera

I 'm trying to render a perspective orthogonal and save it as an image, but don't work

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        override = {'area': area, 'region': area.regions[-1]}
        bpy.ops.view3d.view_pan(override, type='PANRIGHT')
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.filepath = 'persp.png'
```

Comment: In blender jargon "perspective" and "orthogonal" are mutually exclusive.  Are you perhaps thinking of "isometric" instead?

Comment: I need save images with a script:
View-> Rigth, Left, Back, Front 
in Orthogonal View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this scene is not an animation, you can use the time axis to animate your camera.  At frame 1 keyframe your camera's location and rotation so it is viewing the Right image.  At frame 2 keyframe the camera so it is viewing the Left image.  Continue frame by frame until you have all the views you want.  Then adjust the start and end frame of the animation to match the number of images you want.

Make sure your camera is configured for orthogonal.

Now when you render the animation the camera will hop around to the different locations for the shots and each frame of the animation will be one of the views you want.

Answer (score 1):

My solution...

```
bpy.ops.object.camera_add()
bpy.data.cameras['Camera'].type = 'ORTHO'
bpy.data.cameras['Camera'].ortho_scale = 180
bpy.ops.object.lamp_add( location=(30, -5, 90), rotation=(0, 0, 0))
# Set orthogonal position 
bpy.data.objects["Camera"].location = (30, -5, 90)
bpy.data.objects["Camera"].rotation_euler = (0, 0, 0)
# Save result as png image
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "orthogonal1"
bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)
```